# Where do I put the translations for Ember-I18n in Ember-CLI?

Tags: ember-cli, ember-i18n

I am new to ember, and ember-cli and I'm still learning where everything goes. I'm trying to add multilingual support with the [ember-i18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n) module.

I have the dependencies installed with bower

```
bower install cldr ember-i18n --save
```

And I've got my imports working in `Brocfile.js`

```js
app.import('vendor/cldr/plurals.js');
app.import('vendor/ember-i18n/lib/i18n.js');
```

In my app the i18n handlebar helper is working

`{{t hello}}` gives me "Missing translation: hello"

I don't know where to put or reference a file in the ember-cli folder structure that contains the translations.

Per ember-i18n documentaton it would look something like this

```js
Ember.I18n.translations = {
    hello: "Hello World",
}
```

I tried sticking it in `app.js` just to see it working but got the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'translations' of undefined
```

Comment: the lib name is CLDR not CDLR, please fix `bower install` line

Comment: I have no idea why but importing cldr **before** ember-i18n basically prevented my templates to render. Reverting the 2 lines fixed the issue. No idea why!

Comment: Nevermind: cldr must be included before ember-i18n to work. My mistake was to not have set CLDR.defaultLanguage = "en". Now everything is working!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add your translations within an `initializer` ([docs here](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#naming-conventions)). 
With ember-cli you can generate one by doing `ember generate initializer i18n` on the command line.

Within the initializer you can set the translations:

```
var TRANSLATIONS = {
  'user.edit.title': 'Edit User',
  'user.followers.title.one': 'One Follower',
  'user.followers.title.other': 'All {{count}} Followers',
  'button.add_user.title': 'Add a user',
  'button.add_user.text': 'Add',
  'button.add_user.disabled': 'Saving...'
};
var i18nInitializer = {
  name: 'i18n',
  initialize: function() {
    Ember.I18n.translations = TRANSLATIONS;
  }
};
export default i18nInitializer;
```

If you want to retrieve the language data via ajax in a `java-properties` file you can retrieve it with ajax and parse it with [java-properties.js](https://github.com/willemdewit/java.properties.js). It is also available via Bower

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issues as Weston and after some research I've implemented a solution to this that can dynamically load a language specified by the user.  This is probably too late for the OP, but I'm putting it here for future reference for anyone else that may have questions about this process.

My solution may not be the ideal way to handle doing this but it seems to work nicely with my site.

I'm using Ember-cli and included ember-i18n, for internationalization, as well as CLDR to handle plurals.  My site uses a cookie to store the user language, which is used to load the appropriate language file when the site loads.  The cookie is also passed along to the REST service (some API calls return objects that could contain translated text).  I'm using jQuery-cookie for my cookie handling.

---

First I created my translations files, one for each language, which are just javascript files that I will then load in using $.getScript.  I stored them in a 'translations' folder within the public/javascript folder Ember-cli created.

**translations-en.js**

```
Ember.I18n.translations = {
  'hello' : 'Hello World!',
  ...
}
```

**translations-fr.js**

```
Ember.I18n.translations = {
  'hello' : 'Bonjour Monde!',
  ...
}
```

Then I set the initializer for CLDR, which sets the default language based on the user-lang cookie my site uses - if the cookie doesn't yet exist it defaults to 'en' and creates the cookie.

**\app\initializers\cldr.js**

```
export default {
  name: 'cldr',

  initialize: function() {
    var lang = $.cookie('user-lang');

    if (lang === undefined) {  // no cookie exists yet
      lang = 'en';
      $.cookie('user-lang', lang, {expires:365, path:'/'});
    }

    CLDR.defaultLanguage = lang; 
  }
};
```

Now in the Application Route's beforeModel function I grab the translations file based on the value stored in CLDR.defaultLanguage.

**\app\routes\application.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  beforeModel: function() {
    $.getScript('./javascript/translations/translations-' + CLDR.defaultLanguage + '.js')
      .fail(function(jqxhr, reason, exception) {
        // handle failure
      });
  }
});
```

If your site has a large number of translation strings, or many languages, you may not want to have your translation files included every time someone loads your app or it could take a while to load.  In that case you can replace this getScript with an ajax call and get the file served up by your backend.  In my case there are not too many translation strings so this is ok.

Now any time a user wants to change the language all I have to do is update the value of my user-lang cookie and then reload the site, which will go through the initializer and beforeModel functions again and load the appropriate language file.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    changeLanguage: function(lang) {
      $.cookie('user-lang', lang); 

      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
});
```

Any time the user reloads the page or returns to the site their last selected language will be loaded from the cookie by default.  Of course, the user could delete their cookie or log in from a different browser, in which case the site will return to the default 'en' language.  To get around this the user's language selection would need to persist somewhere on the back-end and be fetched on app load - but that's another task.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace is wrong.

You need `Em.I18n.translations`.

Tried it. Works.

> I don't know where to put or reference a file in the ember-cli folder structure that contains the translations.

Me neither. Of course `app.js` works but maybe someone can provide a nice hint. I'm pretty new to all that ember-cli stuff as well...

Comment: Yes! Thanks Doe. I did realize this after fighting with it for awhile. But my main questions still stands, the ember-i18n seems to expect the translations to only include translations for the current language. This would imply there should be some smart process to load the appropriate translation. I would like to put that logic server side and just reference a single file, but I'm unsure how to make a dependancy for ember-cli that is not managed with bower.

Comment: I'm also really interested in this topic. Maybe it's worth it to start a new question just for that.